# How do I get Hudson to generate a Findbugs report without failing due to an exception?

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, hudson, maven-plugin, findbugs

**Update**

As of Hudson Findbugs plug-in version 4.3 this is no longer an issue

**End Update**

As an example of my problem, I'm trying to build the following project http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

I added the following to simple-parent/pom.xml

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
         <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
         <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
         <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And the following to simple-weather/pom.xml and simple-webapp/pom.xml

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I inserted the following horrible equals method into one of the classes to have FindBugs generate some issues (as there is no error on 0 bugs):

```
public boolean equals(Object o) { return true; }
```

I'm using Hudson with a maven2 style project.  The job is aimed at the simple-parent pom with the goals

```
clean site
```

I get the following exception:

```
[INFO] Generating "FindBugs Report" report.
[java] Warnings generated: 2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cannot inherit from final class
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch2(RemoteClassLoader.java:370)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor594.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:274)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:417)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:269)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:123)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:651)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:676)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Version info:

- Maven 2.2.1
- Java 1.5.0_22
- Hudson 1.341 (also found on 1.339) running inside JBoss 4.0.5.GA (same error on 4.2.2.GA and 5.1.0.GA)
- Maven FindBugs plugin 2.3
- Hudson FindBugs plugin 4.1

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Had this exact same problem when I first tried to install the FindBugs plugin *yesterday*.. Was banging my head here thinking it was me! Thanks for the quick question & update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the FindBugs FAQ, this problem occurs when the wrong version of Apache BCEL is being used (see [Q2: When I click the "Find Bugs!" button, I get a NoSuchMethodError or VerifyError](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q2)). In your case, I suspect that the maven-findbugs-plugin is getting the BCEL library from JBoss because of some obscure classloading issue. There are some very similar bugs in Hudson's Jira, e.g. [HUDSON-5134](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5134) (the hudson findbugs plugin is also affected).

My understanding is that this problem has been introduced **recently** (in v1.338) and, even if there is a workaround, it **is** an Hudson bug (it is a regression, it's not a problem with JBoss).

Now, you have IMO two solutions:

- Use a version of Hudson anterior to v1.338 (the regression was reported for this version) but using an old version and sticking with it is certainly not really a viable solution.
- Remove or replace the `bcel.jar` of JBoss (in `server/SERVERNAME/lib`) with the version used by the maven-findbugs-plugin (see [dependencies](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/2.3/dependencies.html)). I'm not able to say how this will affect JBoss exactly (If you remove it, it seems that you will loose the ability to run JBoss in debug-mode but I can't say if everything will work fine if you replace it).

Whatever you'll do, please create a new Jira issue (http://issues.hudson-ci.org/) as this **is a regression in Hudson**. They have marked [HUDSON-5134](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5134) as "Won't fix" because there is a workaround but I don't think that messing with JBoss libraries is a good solution (I'm repeating myself but this is a Hudson bug). So, insisting and letting Hudson developers know that other users are affected by this problem will help all the entire community (at least, I hope so).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers provided are better, but one alternative to add: use Ant or batch file to create a separate build step that doesn't care that the FindBugs step failed.  The Hudson plug-in can still be used to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

As Pascal points out, there is a similar bug filed - [HUDSON-5134](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5134) - and that bug indicates the behavior started with Hudson release 1.338.  Since Hudson releases once a week, it can be difficult to pin down which version introduced a bug.  I notice there was a classloader related change released with Hudson [version 1.337](http://hudson-ci.org/changelog.html#v1.337) ([HUDSON-5048](http://HUDSON-5048)), and I suspect that is causing the problem here, but I don't have direct evidence of that.

But that likely means you need to roll back to 1.337 or earlier to avoid this problem.